# Silverlight 5 and nUnit

Tags: silverlight, nunit

I'm currently using a version of nUnit 2.5.x that was built to work with Silverlight 4 runtime.  It works really well, but we're now planning to move to Silverlight 5.  I haven't been able to find a version of nUnit that has been built to work with the Silverlight 5 runtime.  Does anyone know if this exists, or if there are other alternatives?  I've considered MSTest, but our current tests use a lot of TestCase and ValueSource attributes.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case someone else stumbles upon this, nUnitLite supports Silverlight 5. There's a NuGet package for nUnitLite.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know where did you find NUnit 2.5 that can work (??) with SL4 (How ??) but this is what I did for uni-testing my SL5 application

- Create full .NET Framework 4 Application (Not 'Client profile')
- Added reference to SL5 project (to the .DLL file) and NUnit libs
- Compile (there will be a lot of errors)

  The main problem is SL .DLL file search for running assembles (for example: `System.Windows.dll`, `System.Windows.Browser.dll` and in very bad case it search for `mscorlib.dll` SL version). You should reference it from .NET project.

  Actually reference correct SL assembly's from .NET project is the most problematic part - once you get it over - you could run regular NUnit test with no problem.

  - Be aware of multyplay redefinition of DependencyObject and choose .NET Framework version: Define NUnit (or else) flag in SL and .NET project and `#if NUnit` all *problematic* `INotifyDataErrorInfo`, `IComamnd`, etc.. interfaces
  - If SL assembly could not be referenced from .NET project just copy it locally to \Debug folder befor running NUnit test
  - Good luck. It's not so easy